# More Stack Exchange sites about CMS

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center

Our [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page has this bullet point:

> **Content management systems (CMSs)** -- There are specific Stack Exchange sites for several CMSs. Use those sites for [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/), [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/), [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/), [Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/), or [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/). Questions about other CMSs may be asked here on Pro Webmasters.

We have some more CMS sites now:

- https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/
- https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/
- https://joomla.stackexchange.com/
- https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/

If we want to keep this bullet point, we should link to these sites, too.

Comment: Some of those sites are not about *using* the CMS, but only for developers.    There isn't actually much that about WordPress that is actually on-topic at the WordPress site.  We would allow questions about using and configuring WordPress here, because such questions would be off-topic there.   We might want to update the language of our FAQ to reflect that as well.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Which sites would that be? I don’t use them, but according to their missions (this little box on the front page) they all welcome (end-)users and developers.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic: "setup, feature, account, and other user support issues - try WordPress.com support -- questions regarding the use of WordPress.com - try WebApps"

Comment: @StephenOstermiller: Ah, I see. I only thought about the 4 new sites. So if we decide to keep this bullet point, the 4 sites could be added, and WordPress could be removed?

Comment: I wish I could up-vote this more than once. Good digging- you struck gold!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could update it to (in alphabetical order):

> **Content management systems (CMSs)** -- There are specific Stack Exchange sites for several CMSs. Use those sites for 
>   [Craft CMS](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/),
>   [Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/),
>   [Expression Engine](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/),
>   [Joomla](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/),
>   [Magento](https://magento.stackexchange.com/),
>   [Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/),
>   [SharePoint](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/),
>   [Tridion](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/), 
>   or [WordPress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/).
>   Questions about other CMSs may be asked here on Pro Webmasters.

Comment: I've gone ahead and made this edit.